# Jagged edge in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to generate a surface plot using `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {U(\x,\y)=(abs(\x)*(abs(\x)>abs(\y)) + abs(\y)*(abs(\x)<=abs(\y)) )*((abs(\x)<1) && (abs(\y)<1)) + 1*((abs(\x)>=1) || (abs(\y)>=1)) + max(2*\x-2,0) - min(2*\x+2,0) + max(2*\y-2,0) - min(2*\y+2,0);}]
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap name    = viridis,
        width            = 8in,
        height           = 6in,
        view             = {25}{11},
        grid             = major,
        domain           = -2:2,
        y domain         = -2:2,
        ]
        \addplot3 [surf,samples at={-2,-1.95,...,2}] {U(\x,\y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in a jagged bottom left edge.
[image: Surface plot]

There are some line intersection issues as well.
[image: Zoomed surface plot]

Any ideas on how to fix these?

Comment: I think the explanation is very simple: there are no triangular surface elements, only rectangular ones. However, on the diagonal you'd need triangular ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is very simple: there are no triangular surface elements, only rectangular ones. However, on the diagonal you'd need triangular ones to draw the thing in one stretch. This would mean using `patchplots`. Assuming you do not want those (please tell me if I am wrong), you may draw the thing in two gos.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {U(\x,\y)=((abs(\x)<1) && (abs(\y)<1))
    +((abs(\x)>=1) || (abs(\y)>=1)) + max(2*\x-2,0) - min(2*\x+2,0) 
    + max(2*\y-2,0) - min(2*\y+2,0);}]
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap name    = viridis,
        width            = 8in,
        height           = 6in,
        view             = {25}{11},
        grid             = major,
        domain           = -2:2,
        y domain         = -2:2,
        ]
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0,0) -- (-1,-1,1)  -- (1,-1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- cycle;
        \addplot3 [surf,samples=21,domain=-{sqrt(2)}:{sqrt(2)},
            y domain= -{sqrt(2)}:{sqrt(2)}] 
        ({(x+y)/sqrt(2)},{(x-y)/sqrt(2)},%
            {max(abs((x+y)/sqrt(2)),abs((x-y)/sqrt(2)))});
        \end{scope} 
        \addplot3 [surf,samples=41] {U(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, the inner function, i.e. for `|x|<1` and `|y|<1` is just `max(abs(x),abs(y))`.

Comment: You could also just clip the jagged edges away (and make the plot become a tiny bit smaller in the inner region).